# ace editor (static) to highlight code (grunt task)

Tags: gruntjs, ace-editor

I am trying to use the **"ace-editor"** to highlight code for a documentation.
I also want to do this in a grunt task.

Has anybody done this before or knows if it is possible?

I am currently using **"highlight.js"** which works very well, but does not support syntax-highlighting for **"less.js"**

#### Tested: (does not highlight as I want)

`hljs.highlightAuto(grunt.file.read('myfile.less')).value`

#### Best result: (setting *"java"* as lang)

`hljs.highlight('java',grunt.file.read('myfile.less')).value`

It currently looks like this (which is OK but not perfect)
http://more-or-less.org/

#### Also appreciated:

any other highlighters that could work (needs to work well for .less code)

#### More Info

- the documentation is for a less.js mixin library
- I am generating the documentation from the actual library

  - using a git submodule
  - reading files and then injecting them into a template (jade)
- generator can be found here https://github.com/pixelass/more-or-less-docs

Answer (score 1):

You can find ace demo for using highlighter at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/static-highlighter/server.js
Basically you need to create a wrapper that, provides same api as `hljs` but calls Ace interanlly.